# Is it possible to deserialize .ser file and use that data as an input in C?

Tags: c, hashmap, deserialization

I am trying to serialize the hashmap into .ser file in Java and deserialize it in C. 
I searched for using .ser file in other language but it seems .ser file is specified for Java. 
Is there any way that I can use .ser file in C?

Comment: You might consider a more portable format, like json.